# Iterate Through Tab Components in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, tabs, iterator

I need to determine which tabs in a JTabbedPane need updated by determining the contents of each tab's component.  From what I can determine, there is no way to iterate through each tab using the default JTabbedPane model.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could do in this situation?

Answer (score 16):

if you use something like:

```
int totalTabs = tabbedPane.getTabCount();
for(int i = 0; i < totalTabs; i++)
{
   Component c = tabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(i);
   //other stuff
}
```

Could give you a start point to do what you want.

Comment: The tabs in question also are able to be removed.  Does JTabbedPane keep the indices in a sequential order (e.g. if original tab indices are: 0,1,2,3,4 and 3 is removed, is the new tab index 0,1,2,3 versus 0,1,2,4).

Comment: It's an index, not an identifier. The indices change as tabs are removed.

Comment: I thnk you want to use `getComponentAt` not `getTabbedComponentAt`, one returns the component of the tabbedPane, one returns the component *in* the tab.

Answer (score 2):

How about [getTabCount()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getTabCount%28%29) and [getTabComponentAt( int index )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getTabComponentAt%28int%29)?

Comment: getTabComponentAt is used for rendering, not for looping over tabs

Comment: @GerritCap the question is too vague to be sure what the OP is _really_ after

Comment: @GerritCap - The OP explicitly asks for a way to "iterate through each tab". One way to do that is with the methods above. The `getTabComponent()` method provides a Component. That component could be used for more than just rendering -- e.g., it could be examined or modified.

Answer (score 0):

use `getComponentAt(int index)` from container